# Sencha Touch Global Variables

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I am working on a Sencha Touch application and I am learning it great because I love JavaScript.

This is my app.js

```
var App = new Ext.Application({
    name: 'My First App',

    //BaseURL: 'http://mydomain.com/testing/first/services/',

    launch: function() {
        this.views.viewport = new this.views.Viewport();

        // this.BaseURL = "http://mydomain.com/testing/first/services/";
    }
});
```

This is one of my Store.

```
var newsStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'News',
    sorters: [{
        property: 'PostedOn',
        direction: 'DESC'
    }],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://mydomain.com/testing/first/services/News.php',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            root: 'News',
            record: 'New'   
        }
    },
    getGroupString: function(record) {
        if (record && record.data.PostedOn) {
            return record.get('PostedOn').toDateString();
        }
        else {
            return '';
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
```

Now the question is, if I can create a global variable across whole application? It's named **BaseURL** and I can use it among all Data Stores and when need to change it, I just change this to reflect across whole application.

I need to know two things.

1. How to declare a global application level variable.
2. How to access that variable in views and stores.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would recommend adding your custom global variables to the application namespace, like this:

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'MyApp',
  launch: function() { },
  apiToken: 'foo'
});
```

This way you will be able to access these custom variables after your application has launched:

```
MyApp.app.apiToken
```

It works with functions, too:

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'MyApp',
  launch: function() { },
  apiToken: 'foo',
  getApiToken: function() { return this.apiToken; }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a global variable normally as you would do without  Sencha:

```
var BaseURL = "http://mydomain.com/testing/first/services/";
```

And then to use it:

```
proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: BaseUrl + 'News.php',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            root: 'News',
            record: 'New'   
        }
    }
```

**EDIT :**

If you want to declare it as a member of your App instance do:

```
var App = new Ext.Application({
    name: 'My First App',
    launch: function() {
        this.views.viewport = new this.views.Viewport();
        this.BaseURL = "http://mydomain.com/testing/first/services/";
    }
});
```

and then:

```
proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: App.BaseUrl + 'News.php',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            root: 'News',
            record: 'New'   
        }
    }
```

Comment: inside Application instance? I would like to do inside App instance and to access it via App instance.

Comment: See also Ext.namespace() and Ext.Application documentation. "name" property should contain no spaces and can be used as global identifier.

Answer (score 1):

After some sencha updates we can do it:

```
var App = Ext.application({
   name: 'Myapp',
   serviceUrl: 'https://example',

   launch: function() {


   } 
});


Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: Myapp.app.servideUrl,
    withCredentials: true,
    useDefaultXhrHeader: true,
    method: 'post',
    scope: this,

    params: {
        cmd:        'connect',
        id:         login,
        password:   pass,
        version:    1
    },

    success: function (response) {

        var result = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);            

        if (result.result.status === 'connected'){
            this.loginSucess(result);
        }else{                                         
            this.loginFail(result);
        }
    },

    failure: function (response) {                    
        this.loginFail();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886363/sencha-touch-2-global-variables-access-everywhere/15107237#15107237) answer, may help You.

Specially if, You want to pass params to store.