# Sencha Touch 2 Global Variables - Access everywhere

Tags: javascript, cordova, global-variables, sencha-touch-2

I know this question was already posted in StackOverflow but I either didnt understand or sencha changed somewhat.

My app loads a form panel for login, then I would like to save the user info that have just loged on. This way I can change my view anytime I want and still know the name of the loged in user.

Here is my main code:

```
//<debug>
Ext.Loader.setPath({
    'Ext': 'sdk/src'
});

//</debug>
Ext.application({
    name: 'APP',

    loadedUser: 'the test',

    requires: ['Ext.MessageBox'],

    views: ['Main', 'Home', 'Login'],

    models: ['User'],

    stores: ['Users'],

    controllers: ['Main'],

    icon: {
        57: 'resources/icons/Icon.png',
        72: 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png',
        114: 'resources/icons/Icon@2x.png',
        144: 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png'
    },

    phoneStartupScreen: 'resources/loading/Homescreen.jpg',
    tabletStartupScreen: 'resources/loading/Homescreen~ipad.jpg',

    setLoadedUser: function(arg) {
        this.loadedUser = arg;
    },

    launch: function() {
        // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
        Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

        // Initialize the main view
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('APP.view.Main'));
    },

    onUpdated: function() {
        Ext.Msg.confirm("Application Update", "This application has just successfully been updated to the latest version. Reload now?", function() {
            window.location.reload();
        });
    }
});
```

The 'loadedUser' its what I wanted to be my global variable, and the method setLoadedUser(arg) its suposed to change that value.

I can access 'loadedUser' no problem, but I can't change its value.
Another question: loadedUser can it be an array/data structure?

Comment: How are you accessing the function? This works for me. Remember you should access it like: `APP.app.setLoadedUser('test');`. And yes, it can be any value. :)

Comment: That was it. Submit as an answer so can make it yours :) Thanks for the protip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you accessing the function? This works for me. Remember you should access it like this:

```
APP.app.setLoadedUser('test');
```

And yes, it can be any value. :)

Comment: i can't access this in my stores and controllers .. why is that so?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use localStorage to, set/get Your variables:

Set it as:
`localStorage.setItem('currentUserId', userID)`

Get it as:
`localStorage.getItem('currentUserId')`

You can use it, anywhere in Your script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the works when the function is inside of the app.js file.
It does not work if the function is inside of the controller file.

So if you have a project application called IronMan, the call from the view code to the global function, `flyAway()`, in your `app.js` file would look like:

```
IronMan.app.flyAway();
```

Comment: I honestly don't get this answer.
As shown above, my app.js contains the function that i want to use as a global at the root level of `Ext.application` in the app.js file.
Am I missing something?

Comment: I just tried to call `launch()` from the scope where I need to call `getLoggedUserDetails()` and it works. I don't really get WTF my custom functions it's not being recognised.